# How to use non-Latin languages for Android downloadable fonts?

Tags: android, google-fonts, android-downloadable-fonts

After reading the [documentation for Google Fonts API for Android](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/android), I've successfully added different font weights beside regular and bold. But, the downloaded font isn't displaying for non-Latin characters. The difference can be seen between non-Latin letters (i.e. Cyrillic) and properly displayed Latin (like numbers and punctuation).

I even tried copying the web version of the API, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
    app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
    app:fontProviderQuery="name=Montserrat&amp;subset=cyrillic"
    app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```

but nothing happened, because `subset` is not a valid keyword.

Is there any way to specify which scripts should be included, like with the web version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, Google Fonts API supports non-Latin characters for downloadable fonts by default. I have tested this on [this sample project](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/DownloadableFonts) with the `29.0.0` build tools.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported yet. You must use custom fonts that support cyrillic symbols for apply cyrillic. Put their it 'font' folder and get with `ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont)` .